# Xcode 13 ('Product' is ambiguous)

Tags: ios, swift, class, nsobject, xcode13

I have updated XCode to 13.0. And build my app. Now it is showing error as following

```
//MARK:- UberRide
class UberRide: NSObject {
var rideImgUrl: URL
var rideName: String
var ridePrice: Double = 0.0
var rideTime: String

   init(product: Product) {
       self.rideImgUrl = product.imageURL!
       self.rideName = product.name!
       if let price = product.priceDetails?.minimumFee {
        self.ridePrice = price
       }
       rideTime = ""
   }
}
```

Error is **'Product' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context** and **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous without more context  What is this `Product` type? Where is it defined?

Comment: What is `Product` Here ??

Answer (score 1):

Probably your type conflicts with new [Product](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product?changes=_2) in StoreKit?

Check your imports. Do you need the full `StoreKit` there? You could also import only specific classes, thus preventing the conflict.

If you need to use both types in one file, you can always distinguish them by fully qualified name, e.g:

`MyProject.Product` or `StoreKit.Product`.